# An instance's hyperparameter of SGDRegressor is tol=-np.infty doesn't work

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I'm studying machine learning from handson-ml2 book. The topic is early stopping on stochastic gradient descent. I'm running the following code in Pycharm:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

np.random.seed(42)
m = 100
X = 6 * np.random.rand(m, 1) - 3
y = 2 + X + 0.5 * X**2 + np.random.randn(m, 1)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X[:50], y[:50].ravel(), test_size = 0.5, random_state = 10)

# Verileri hazırlama
poly_scaler = Pipeline([
    ("poly_features", PolynomialFeatures(degree = 90, include_bias = False)),
    ("std_scaler", StandardScaler())
    ])

X_train_poly_scaled = poly_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val_poly_scaled = poly_scaler.transform(X_val)

sgd_reg = SGDRegressor(max_iter = 1, tol = -np.infty, warm_start = True,
                       penalty = None, learning_rate = "constant", eta0 = 0.0005, random_state = 42)
minimum_val_error = float("inf")
best_epoch = None
best_model = None

for epoch in range(1000):
    sgd_reg.fit(X_train_poly_scaled, y_train) 
    y_val_predict = sgd_reg.predict(X_val_poly_scaled)
    val_error = mean_squared_error(y_val, y_val_predict)
    if val_error < minimum_val_error:
        minimum_val_error = val_error
        best_epoch = epoch
        best_model = deepcopy(sgd_reg)

print("best_epoch:", best_epoch, "best_model:", best_model)
```

where I'm getting this error:

```
 raise InvalidParameterError(sklearn.utils._param_validation.InvalidParameterError: The 'tol' parameter of SGDRegressor must be a float in the range [0, inf) or None. Got -inf instead.
```

This error says you can't set the 'tol' parameter to '-inf'. But in the book it seems working. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using the scikit-learn library to implement your SGDRegressor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book you are referring to where setting the `tol` hyperparameter to `-inf` appears to work could be due to a difference in versions or implementations in the `SGDRegressor` class.

If you'd like to copy the code from the book without making any modifications, make sure you're using the same library that was used in the book. As an extra measure, make sure the versions match. You can check this by doing `library.__version__`.

Else if you're fine with making a small change to the code provided, you should be able to simply set `tol` to `0` (the behavior should be identical, the model will ignore that parameter and keep on training until `max_iter` or some other stopping criterion is met).

Comment: When I set tol parameter to '0' code runned the way I want. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @Utku Can I'm glad you found it helpful. If you could take a second, it'd greatly help me if you could mark my answer as the solution (click the checkmark).